# LogMeIn Hamachi VPN

Tags: security, encryption, vpn

How do I connect my Android phone or tablet to a [LogMeIn Hamachi VPN](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/)? Is it even possible?

LogMeIn has command line [clients for Linux](https://secure.logmein.com/labs/), and of course Android has built-in VPN settings.

Is there some way to hack my Android to get it on the Hamachi VPN? I'll try almost anything no matter how involved. Root and non-root answers welcome (I have root access).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in [this how-to](http://techcornercdog918.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-hamachi-on-android.html), you can do this by installing a "chrooted" Linux distro on Android such as [Ubuntu](http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/), and then downloading, installing and configuring Hamachi manually.

> Hamachi is a vpn program which can be used to link up computers. With
>   hamachi on an android you would be able to access the files on
>   multiple computers from anywhere in the world (provided that you have
>   wifi, 3g, 4g or any other type of internet connection on your phone)
>   this is useful when programs like dropbox can't hold the file that you
>   want because it is too large and you know that you will need it at
>   some point when you are on the go.  To get hamachi on android there
>   are a few requirements which must be met first:
>
> 1. Internet access.
> 2. Ubuntu/Debian/Backtrack or any other Linux distro on your phone.
> 3. Rooted phone (root access).
>
> Once those 3 requirements have been met you should be set to go.
>
> 1. Boot up the Linux distro on your phone
> 2. Either open up the browser on the distro or the browser on your phone.
> 3. go to http://www.mediafire.com/?jwng92o6j56ov8l and download the hamachi file. If you did this on the distro then you may skip to step 5A
> 4. If it hasn't happened already, move that whole file to emmc on your phone
> 5. (5A. Move the hamachi file from the downloads folder in the distro to
>      `/root`)  Open up the distro and copy that hamachi file from `/mnt/emmc` to `/root`
> 6. Open terminal and cd into that directory and run the following commands
> 7. `sh ./install`
> 8. `mkdir /dev/net`
> 9. `mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200`
> 10. `apt-get install sudo`
> 11. `apt-get install libcrypto++7`
> 12. `ln -s /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7`
> 13. `sudo tuncfg`
> 14. `hamachi-init`
> 15. `hamachi start`
> 16. `hamachi login`
> 17. `hamachi set-nick` [enter desired nickname here]
> 18. `hamachi join` [networkname] [password]
> 19. DONE.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you! I will try this out tonight hopefully.